# How to get County Name from reverse GeoLocation look up?

Tags: python, geolocation

I'm using python and the library `from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim` and I'm parsing through some Lat/Long coordinates and I want to get the county of the coordinates.

This is what I'm doing:

```
def getCounty(data):
    try:
        #print(data["geo"]["coordinates"])   # Getting Lat/Long coordinates
        geo_data = data["geo"]["coordinates"]
        geo_detail = geolocator.reverse(geo_data)

    except TypeError,e:
        geo_data = "null"
        geo_detail = "N/A"

    ctr = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    if(geo_detail != "N/A"):
        while(geo_detail[i]!= ',' and ctr == 4):
            j=j+1
            if(ctr == 3):
                i=j+1
            if(geo_detail[j] == ','):
                ctr = ctr+1
        county = geo_detail
    else:
        county = "No Location Provided"


    return county[i:j]
```

This for some reason returns `()`

when I do: `return county`, It does return all the information from those coordinates.

It seems like I'm not able to get the substring of the variable `county`

How can I get the county attribute or what are other ways I could get the county?

Comment: could you please provide one example of a Lat/Long coordinates in `data` that you are passing into `getCounty(data)`?

Comment: input: [43.03333333, -88.06666667]
Output: 12343, West Ripley Avenue, Wauwatosa, Milwaukee County, Wisconsin, 53226, United States of America

Comment: Ok, looks like you can just split that output string on the comma, and get the 4th index (the county), right?: `return geo_detail.address.split(",")[3]` - > `Milwaukee County`

Comment: Thank you! that works! can you put it as an Answer to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split that output string on the comma, and get the 4th index (the county):

```
return geo_detail.address.split(",")[3] # Milwaukee County
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that this won't always work for all addresses. Some returns for this don't include the street number (even if provided in the lookup) and then this will then return the state.

Try:

```
[x.strip() for x in location.address.split(',') if 'County' in x ][0]
```

This will always return the county if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since locations are not all in the same format you should use:

```
location = geolocator.reverse("47.173056,-114.553611")

line = location.address
line = line.replace(',','')
words = line.lower().split()
print(words)

ind = (words.index('county')-1)
print(words[ind])
```